# How to replace an object in object array in javascript (lodash)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have following object array:

```
var arr = [
  {
    id    : "a1",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "abc",
    status: false
  },
  {
    id    : "a2",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "def",
    status: true
  },
  ...
]
```

I have this object:

```
var obj = {
  id      : "a1",
  guid    : "sdfsfd",
  ...
  value   : "xyz",
  status  :  true
}
```

I need to replace the object in the array with this object where the "id" is same. So the resulting array will be:

```
var arr = [
  {
    id    : "a1",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "xyz",
    status: true
  },
  {
    id    : "a2",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "def",
    status: true
  },
  ...
]
```

Additionally I need to add this object to the array if an object with that id doesn't  exists.

How to achieve this using minimal [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) code? 
Looking for something like

```
arr = _.merge_by_key(arr,obj,"id");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do it with `_.unionBy`

```
var res = _.unionBy([obj], arr, 'id');
```

but check a note at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265987/how-to-replace-an-object-in-object-array-in-javascript-lodash/42266640?noredirect=1#comment71690056_42266640)

Comment: This is very creative, but may do a lot more work than needed. It will search through the rest of the items in the array to also remove duplicates.

Comment: @4castle i dont sure about "remove duplicates", can you show proof?

Comment: Observe the output [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13qpoy36/1/).

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.findIndex()`

```
var i = arr.findIndex(o => o.id === obj.id);
if (arr[i]) { arr[i] = obj } else { arr.push(obj) };
```

Comment: This is the best solution, as it doesn't require any external libraries. Thanks!

Comment: Very elegant approach +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`_.findIndex`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findIndex) with the [`_.matchesProperty`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#matchesProperty) shorthand:

```
var index = _.findIndex(arr, ['id', obj.id]);
arr[index >= 0 ? index : arr.length] = obj;
```

```js
var arr = [{
  id: "a1",
  guid: "sdfsfd",
  value: "abc",
  status: false
}, {
  id: "a2",
  guid: "sdfsfd",
  value: "def",
  status: true
}];

var obj = {
  id      : "a1",
  guid    : "sdfsfd",
  value   : "xyz",
  status  :  true
};

var index = _.findIndex(arr, ['id', obj.id]);
arr[index >= 0 ? index : arr.length] = obj;
                        
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a lodash solution that uses [keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy) to create an object wherein each item in the collection is represented by their `id`, [set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set) to override the new object or possibly add the new object and lastly [values](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#values) to get the array representation of the object.

```
var result = _(arr).keyBy('id').set(obj.id, obj).values().value();
```

```js
var arr = [
  {
    id    : "a1",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    value : "abc",
    status: false
  },
  {
    id    : "a2",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    value : "def",
    status: true
  }
];

var obj = {
  id      : "a1",
  guid    : "sdfsfd",
  value   : "xyz",
  status  :  true
}

var result = _(arr).keyBy('id').set(obj.id, obj).values().value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can loop and use 'splice' function:

```
var added = false;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
   if(arr[i].id === obj.id){
        arr.splice(i,1,obj);
        added = true;
        break;
   }
}

if(!added) arr.push(obj);
```

EDIT: missed added condition

Comment: This won't add the object if the id wasn't found in the array.