# How to set specific property value of all objects in a javascript object array (lodash)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have following object array:

```
var arr = [
  {
    id    : "a1",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "abc",
    status: "active"
  },
  {
    id    : "a2",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "def",
    status: "inactive"
  },
  {
    id    : "a2",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "def"
  },
  ...
]
```

How to **set "status" property of each object to "active"**. So the resulting array will be:

```
var arr = [
  {
    id    : "a1",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "abc",
    status: "active"
  },
  {
    id    : "a2",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "def",
    status: "active"
  },
  {
    id    : "a2",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",
    ...
    value : "def",
    status: "active"
  },
  ...
]
```

Additionally this should create the property "active" if doesn't exists.

I can do this using for loops. But I'm pretty much sure [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) can do this in one line like:

```
arr = _.set_property(arr, "status", "active");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace an object in object array in javascript (lodash)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265987/how-to-replace-an-object-in-object-array-in-javascript-lodash)

Comment: Hi try this link its trying to do the same but by index. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641731/is-there-a-function-in-lodash-to-replace-matched-item

Comment: `arr.forEach(it=>it.status='active');` use the force Luke. Take time to look at global standard JavaScript objects and methods for `Array` and `Object`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects instead of using duplication of outdated libraries and thereby maintain practical knowledge

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indeed, you don't *need* [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs), but the question is tagged Lodash, and using Lodash offers some useful defenses that reduces the risk of errors. This solution utilizes [_.forEach](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach) and [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs/#set)

```
 // _.forEach won't throw errors if arr is not an array...
 _.forEach(arr, function (obj) {
    // _.set won't throw errors if obj is not an object. With more complex objects, if a portion of the path doesn't exist, _.set creates it
     _.set(obj, 'status', 'active');
 });
```

If you wanted to make it abstract, you could build a Lodash mixin:

```
_.mixin({
    setProperty: function(arr, key, val) {
        _.forEach(arr, function (obj) {
            _.set(obj, path, val);
        });
    }
});
```

Then, you could use it exactly as you described:

```
_.setProperty( arr, 'status', 'active' );
```

Comment: Nice 'mixin' example!

Another possibility, though a bit of a 'loaded' one-liner: `_.map(arr, function(o) { _.set(o, 'status', 'active'); });`.

Comment: Another one-liner: `_.each(arr, itm => _.set(itm, 'status', 'active'));`

Comment: you don't need lodash to do simple stuff like this.

Answer (score 28):

You **don't** need `lodash` for this.

---

The first object is missing your status property and it will be added.

Showing **two** ways:

**IMMUTABLE VERSION**  (We create a new array using `map`)

```
const arrImmutableVersion = arr.map(e => ({...e, status: "active"}));
```

**MUTABLE VERSIONS**  (We change the original array)

```
arr.forEach((el)=>{el.status = "active";})
```

or

```
arr.forEach(function(el){el.status = "active";})
```

```js
var arr = [
  {
    id    : "a1",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",   
    value : "abc"
  },
  {
    id    : "a2",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",   
    value : "def",
    status: "inactive"
  },
  {
    id    : "a2",
    guid  : "sdfsfd",   
    value : "def",
    status: "active"
  } 
];

// SHOWING THREE WAYS HOW YOU CAN DO IT

// MUTABLE VERSIONS - We change the original array
arr.forEach((el)=>{el.status = "active";}) // ES6
// or
arr.forEach(function(el){el.status = "active";}) 
//or
// IMMUTABLE VERSION - We create a new array using `map`
const arrImmutableVersion = arr.map(e => ({...e, status: "active"})); // ES6
//--------------------------------------------------------------


// RESULTS:
console.log("logging results of object 'arr'");
console.log(arr);
console.log("---------------------------------------------------------");
console.log("logging results of object 'arrImmutableVersion'");
console.log(arrImmutableVersion);
```

Comment: Immutable ES6/ES2015 version: `const newArr = arr.map(e => ({...e, status: "active"}))`

Answer (score 3):

A way simpler and  and cleaner way !

If you want to use func programming in a proper manner

```
  myArray = myArray.map(arrayElem => {
    arrayElem.property = newValue
    return arrayElem
  })
```

Comment: ESLint: Assignment to property of function parameter 'i'.(no-param-reassign)